# add administrator in managed metadata service using powershell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to creating Managed Metadata Service using powershell.

powershell command is :

New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name $MetadataServiceName -AdministratorAccount "domain\SP_Crawl" -DatabaseServer $instanceName -DatabaseName $MetadataServiceDB -ApplicationPool $AppPool -SyndicationErrorReportEnabled

its working fine if in -AdministratorAccount i am adding single user i.e. "domain\SP_Crawl".

but i want to add multiple user as an administrator like "domain\SP_Crawl,domain\SP_Farm"

but its not working.

Please help me how can i set multiple user in -AdministratorAccount

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its my mistake.

there is a space between "domain\SP_Crawl, domain\SP_Farm" that the reason its not working.

it should be like:

```
New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name $MetadataServiceName -AdministratorAccount "domain\SP_Crawl,domain\SP_Farm" -DatabaseServer $instanceName -DatabaseName $MetadataServiceDB -ApplicationPool $AppPool -SyndicationErrorReportEnabled
```